# Laravel 5.5 - MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, edit

I have an task using Laravel. Which one on my task, user can edit the data on master data table. I'm using modal pop when user want to edit the data. So the user no need to move the page for edit data. On my task I'm using Laravel 5.5

Here is my code :

This is for tabel modal edit

```
<div class="modal fade" id="edit-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="largeModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header no-bd">
                <h5 class="modal-title">
                    <span class="fw-mediumbold">Detail</span>
                    <span class="fw-light">Data</span>
                </h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-material form-horizontal" method=post action="{{route('masterdataobjek.update', 'test')}}">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <input type="hidden" name="id_objek" id="id_objek_modal" value="">
                            <div class="form-group form-group-default">
                                <label>Nama Objek</label>
                                <input id="objek_nama_modal" type="text" name="objek_nama_modal" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="form-group form-group-default">
                                <label for="comment">Deskripsi Objek</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" name="objek_desc_modal" id="objek_desc_modal" rows="5"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Upload WTO File</label>
                            <div class="form-group form-group-default">
                                <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="objek_wto" id="objek_wto">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer no-bd">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For the button clicked code ;

```
<tbody>
    @foreach ($tabelobjek as $ta => $data)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
        <td>{{ $data->objek_nama}}</td>
        <td style="">{{str_limit($data->objek_desc,15)}}</td>
        <td>
            <div class="form-button-action">
                <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" 
                    class="btn btn-link btn-success btn-lg" data-original-title="Edit" 
                    data-target="#edit-modal" id="edit-button"
                    data-idobjek="{{$data->id_objek}}"
                    data-namaobjek="{{$data->objek_nama}}"
                    data-objekdeskripsi="{{$data->objek_desc}}">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

for trigger button :

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on('click', '#edit-button', function () {
                var namaobjek = $(this).data('namaobjek');
                var objekdeskripsi = $(this).data('objekdeskripsi');
                var idobjek = $(this).data(idobjek)

                $('#id_objek_modal').val(idobjek)
                $('#objek_nama_modal').val(namaobjek);
                $('#objek_desc_modal').val(objekdeskripsi);
            })
        })
```

MasterDataObjekController.php

```
 public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $updateObjek = TbObjek::findOrFail($request->id_objek);
        $updateObjek->update($request->all());
        return back();
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure the route `{{route('masterdataobjek.update', 'test')}}` is a POST method and needs a param like `test`? also, add your web route in the source code

Comment: Did you give my answer a go?

Answer (score 0):

`POST` requests are for creating new records, `PUT` and `PATCH` are for updating records. Refer to the table of HTTP methods on Laravel RESTful containers [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#resource-controllers)

You need to change your form tag from this

`<form class="form-material form-horizontal" method=post action="{{route('masterdataobjek.update', 'test')}}">`

to this

`<form class="form-material form-horizontal" method="put" action="{{route('masterdataobjek.update', 'test')}}">`